# Which of the following statements are true?[NBHM-2016]

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following statements are true?

a. Let $A ∈ M_3(\mathbb R)$ be such that $A^4 = I$, $A \neq ±I$. Then $A^2 + I = 0$.

b. Let $A ∈ M_2(\mathbb R)$ be such that $A^3 = I, A \neq I$. Then $A^2 + A + I = 0.$

c. Let $A ∈ M_3(\mathbb R)$ be such that $A^3 = I$, $A\neq I$. Then $A^2 + A + I = 0.$
My attempt

(a)$f(x)=x^4-1$ will be a anhilating polynomial. minimal polynomial divides anhilating polynomial. $(x+1)$ nor $(x-1)$ won't be a minimal polynomial. Since, $A \neq ±I$. $\det(A)^4=1\implies \det(A)=1,-1,-i or i$.

Case 1:- $\det(A)=1$

possible eigenvalues are

$1. 1,1,1, (x-1)^3$ doesn't divide $x^4-1$, So this is not the characteristic polynomial

$2.1,-1,-1, (x-1)(x+1)^2$ does not divide $x^4-1$, So this is not the characteristic polynomial

$3. i,-i, 1$. This can be the case

Case 1:- $\det(A)=-1$

possible eigenvalues are

$1. -1,1,1$( Not the case)

$2.-1,-1,-1$(not the case)

$3. i,-i, -1$ ( This case can be possible)

other two cases are not possible. since complex roots occur in pairs.

From the above two cases eigen values are distinct. So, $A$ is diagonalizable. So minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial are the same.

Using this method. (b) is true. And (c) is false.

Is there any theorem to reduce my workload?

Comment: why do you need to consider det(A)?  You can just analyse the possible eigenvalues, or play with minimal polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal polynomial of $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ has degree $\leq n$.  We just need to examine factors of the known annihilating polynomial for candidates of the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomials.

(a) $A^4=I$, $n=3$, so the possibilities for minimal polynomials are $x\pm 1$, $x^2\pm 1$, $(x+1)(x^2+1)$, $(x-1)(x^2+1)$.  Since $A\ne\pm I$, only degree $2$ or more is allowed.  So the possibilities for minimal polynomial are $x^2-1, x^2+1, (x+1)(x^2+1), (x-1)(x^2-1)$.  But $x^2+1$ is not possible, because the characteristic polynomial is a real polynomial of degree $n=3$ and has to divide the $n$-th power of the minimal polynomial.  So we cannot rule out the min poly being $(x\pm 1)(x^2+1)$ and indeed we have examples such as $A=\begin{pmatrix}\pm1\\&&1\\&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

(b) $n=2$, and $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ is the factorisation into irreducible real polynomials.  So the only candidates for the minimal polynomial are $x-1$ or $x^2+x+1$.  Since $A\neq I$ the min poly must be $x^2+x+1$ and so $A^2+A+I=0$.  This is not vacuous, e.g.,
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

(c) You can do the analysis, or use the result of (b) and ideas of (a) to get
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&A_{(b)}\end{pmatrix}
$$
as a counterexample, where $A_{(b)}$ is any $2\times 2$-matrix satisfying (b)